# scrapy generate url from database

Tags: scrapy

In my scrapy project, I have to fetch a lot of urls in the database, and these urls are filled by another spider.

Generally I will get the urls from the database and set them to the

`start_urls` property of the spider, however there maybe 1000+ thousands  of urls in the db, and the url can be updated anytime.

So  I wonder if it is possible to read from the database one for each request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are probably lots of way to do this. The first one that comes to mind would be to use `spider_idle` signal to pop new url whenever one is done, this way you'd always have up-to-date url.

```
from scrapy import Spider, signals
from scrapy.exceptions import DontCloseSpider

class MySpider(scrapy.Spider):
    start_urls = ['first_url']

    @classmethod
    def from_crawler(cls, crawler, *args, **kwargs):
        spider = super(MySpider, cls).from_crawler(crawler, *args, **kwargs)
        crawler.signals.connect(spider.spider_idle, signals.spider_idle)
        return spider

    def spider_idle(self, spider):
        new_url = ... #pop url from  database
        if new_url:
            self.crawler.engine.schedule(
                Request(new_url, callback=self.parse), spider)
            raise DontCloseSpider
```

Now once the first url is done being scraped your spider_idle() will be called and there you can schedule a new url, continue this for as long as you're able to pop urls from the database.

Comment: Any docs about the dispatcher? I have not found that in the scrapy docs site.

Comment: @hguser actually it seems that pydispatcher is depricated and now you can connect signals in class method `from_crawler`. As per [scrapy issue #1762](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/issues/1762). See my edit.